# Computability and Logic by Boolos et all Problem 17.1

Tags: logic, meta-math, provability, metalogic

> Show that the existence of a semirecursive set that is not recursive implies that any consistent, axiomatizable extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ fails to prove some correct $\forall$-rudimentary sentence.

If we have a semirecursive set $S$, then there is some recursive relation $R$ such that

\begin{align*}
    \forall x (Sx \leftrightarrow \exists y Rxy) \\
\end{align*}

Every recursive function $R$ is arithmetically definable by some $\exists$-rudimentary formula. $\exists$-rudimentary formulas are closed over existential quantification so for any rudimentary $F_1$ we have rudimentary $F_2$ such that $\exists b \exists c F_1 xbc \leftrightarrow \exists d F_2 xd$. And every $\exists$-rudimentary formula is correct or true in the standard interpretation if and only if it is a theorem of the minimal theory of arithmetic $\mathbf{Q}$. Combining that, for any recursive $R$ we have some rudimentary $F$ such that:

\begin{align*}
    \exists y Rxy \; \text{if and only if} \; (\vdash_{\mathbf{Q}} \exists z F(a,z)) \\
\end{align*}

I'm not sure how I go from here to proving that any consistent, axiomatizable extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ fails to prove some correct $\forall$-rudimentary sentence.

The first, and possibly most important example of a correct but unprovable $\forall$-rudimentary sentence is the consistency sentence:

\begin{align*}
  \lnot \text{Prv}_T(\ulcorner \mathbf{0} = \mathbf{1} \urcorner) \\
\end{align*}

Clearly, in a consistent theory, the consistency sentence is correct, or true in the standard interpretation, but it can't be proven.

How do I use a semirecursive set to demonstrate this?

Can someone give me a hint on how to solve the problem. I'm somewhat stuck on what to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that if $T$ were a consistent axiomatizable extension of $\mathsf{Q}$ which proved all $\forall$-rudimentary sentences, then the *complement* of each semirecursive set must also be recursive - hence every semirecursive set is recursive, which we know isn't true. This is because **the set of things an axiomatizable theory proves is semirecursive**.

In more detail, suppose $\varphi(x,y)$ is $\exists$-rudimentary such that the semirecursive set $$S=\{n: \exists y(\varphi(n,y))\}$$ is not recursive and $T$ is a consistent axiomatizable extension of $\mathsf{Q}$. Let $$X_T=\{n: T\vdash\forall y(\neg\varphi(\underline{n},y))\}.$$ Since $\varphi$ is $\exists$-rudimentary, $T\supseteq\mathsf{Q}$, and $T$ is consistent, we must have $X_T\cap S=\emptyset$; if $T$ were to prove all true $\forall$-rudimentary sentences, we would have $X_T\cup S=\mathbb{N}$ and so $X_T=\mathbb{N}\setminus S$. But since $T$ is axiomatizable the set $X_T$ **is itself semidecidable**! So this would mean that $S$ is co-semidecidable as well as decidable, hence decidable - which we know it isn't.

Comment: I understand that the set of all provable theorems in an axiomatizable theory is semirecursive. How are you concluding that $X_T$ is semidecidable or semirecursive? Once you do that, then you use the complementation principle that if a set and its complement are both semirecursive, then they are both, in fact, recursive.

Comment: @clay $X_T$ is semirecursive for the same reason that the set of theorems of $T$ is semirecursive: given $n$, we just search through all $T$-proofs until (if) we find a $T$-proof of the sentence "$\forall y(\neg\varphi(\underline{n},y))$." (Crucial here is the point that the process of building "$\forall y(\neg\varphi(\underline{n},y))$" from $n$ - or more precisely, the function sending $n$ to the Godel number of the sentence "$\forall y(\neg\varphi(\underline{n},y))$" - is recursive.)